# What are the bugs in this code using leaflet-heat + leaflet-sync?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, heat-map

I am trying to use [Leaflet.Sync](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.Sync). I want to show in the first map, a heatmap created by projecting an array of points (by using [Leaflet-Heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat)). And at the second map, I want to visualize the same array of points as circles.

To do so, I simply copied and edited the code from [jieter](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.Sync/blob/master/examples/dual.html).
And added a couple of lines to show heatmap and points. But apperently I am making a logical mistake since nothing is projected on my map.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Leaflet Sync & HeatMap Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" crossorigin=""></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; }
        #map1, #map2 { width: 49.5%; height: 100%; }
        #map1 { float: left; }
        #map2 { float: right; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map1"></div>
    <div id="map2"></div>
    <script src="L.Map.Sync.js"></script>

<script src="dist/leaflet-heat.js"></script>

<script src="example.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var center = [52.37329359852117, 4.899129867553711];

        var layer1 = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 17,
            attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
        });

        var layer2 = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Tiles courtesy of <a href="http://openstreetmap.se/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap Sweden</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        });

        var map1 = L.map('map1', {
            layers: [layer1],
            center: center,
            zoom: 14
        });

        map1.attributionControl.setPrefix('');

        var map2 = L.map('map2', {
            layers: [layer2],
            center: center,
            zoom: 14,
            zoomControl: false
        });

        map1.sync(map2);
        map2.sync(map1);


//how I try to map???

Points = Points.map1(function (p) { return [p[0], p[1]]; });
var heat = L.heatLayer(Points).addTo(map1);

var circles = L.circle(Points).addTo(map2);




    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the example.js I call:
this is the example.js I used:

```
var Points = [
[52.36357871883421, 4.901500940322876, "1"],
[52.37224229353706, 4.896622002124786, "2"],
[52.37261565705108, 4.8971208930015555, "2"],
[52.37062434850485, 4.894942939281463, "3"],
[52.373103644955755, 4.905285537242889, "3"],
[52.373519576698754, 4.905977547168732, "4"],
[52.373513026622916, 4.906012415885925, "2"],
[52.37262548236409, 4.906870722770691, "1"],
[52.37385690429086, 4.905717372894287, "2107"],
[52.37359981504885, 4.905996322631836, "2298"],
[52.372389674248595, 4.892746210098267, "571"],
[52.372309433699975, 4.892732799053192, "572"],
[52.37387000433956, 4.894344806671143, "240"],
[52.372972642020834, 4.894317984580994, "475"],
[52.37383889171757, 4.8955196142196655, "1756"],
[52.365288640174, 4.890434145927429, "2038"],
[52.37624923624196, 4.8832350969314575, "1078"],
[52.36962374757598, 4.877988696098328, "1047"],
[52.379754808237486, 4.893186092376709, "690"]
[52.384764624206305, 4.883208274841309, "1567"]
];
```

Is there anyone to point out my mistake?

Comment: Any errors in the debugger console or network?

Comment: I didn't @TomazicM

Comment: Well, errors popped up in my [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger) when I copy-pasted this code to a plunkr. There should be the syntax error on the missing array comma, and some `p._latlng is undefined` stuff due to wrong parameters on `L.circle` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of simple mistakes here and there.

First, you're missing a comma in the data array, at the next-to-last line:

```
[52.36962374757598, 4.877988696098328, "1047"],
[52.379754808237486, 4.893186092376709, "690"]   // ← Missing comma here
[52.384764624206305, 4.883208274841309, "1567"]
];
```

Second, you're making a call to `Array.prototype.map1` but that fails, and it seems you wanted to call [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead, i.e.:

```
Points = Points.map1(function (p) { return [p[0], p[1]]; });  // wrong       
Points = Points.map(function (p) { return [p[0], p[1]]; });  // works
```

Keep in mind that by mapping the data array you're removing the data for the heatmap weight of each point, and this is not what you might want to do.

Third, you're passing an array of points to the [`L.circle` factory method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#circle), but the factory method (and the class constructor) expect **one** point **only**. The approach here would be to iterate through the data array and create each circle individually, e.g.:

```
var circles = L.layerGroup().addTo(map2);

Points.forEach(function (point){
  circles.addLayer(L.circleMarker(point));
})
```

Keep in mind that there is more than one way to iterate through all elements of an array (e.g. `for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` loops, `for (var i in arr)` loops and `for (var i of arr)` loops, to name a few).

With those three mistakes fixed, the code works (as seen in a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/dbRQlJJb1GLTduFPoCgM?p=preview)).